# Rails 3.2.1 - Find out template file name being rendered from layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

From the view file I know I can call access the @virtual_path instance variable to get the name of the template file being rendered. When I access this variable from the layout, as expected, I get the layout file name. Is there a way to access the name of the main view template file being rendered from the layout?

Answer (score -1):

Is there a difference between layout and templates?

Maybe one of these thinks is useful for you:

```
@app_name  
@app_path
<%= self._template.identifier %>
```

Comment: I think I'm not being clear enough in my question. So, I'm trying to make a clear distinction between the layout file, and the view files. And in the question Im referring as "template" to any view/layout file. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Are you using rails 3.2? Im trying to use the variables and method you included in your answer and none of them exist.

Comment: None of these 3 work for me in Rails 3.2.8. `@app_name` and `@app_path` are not defined and `_template` method does not exist in the view context.